# Why I2S3 breaks I2C3 at STM32F407?

Tags: stm32

I have some codes like below. This is initialize stage and there is no problem here. Communication are OK.
  `MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_I2S3_Init();
  MX_CAN1_Init();
  MX_I2C3_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  USER_CAN_FilterConfig();
  USER_CAN_Start();
  DEVICE_TAS1_Init(hi2c3,DEVICE_TAS1);
  DEVICE_TAS2_Init(hi2c3,DEVICE_TAS2);
  PCT2075GVX_Init(&hi2c3, DEVICE_PTC);`

After that, there is a function runs in my main.
 `EngineSoundPlayer();`
This function takes a constanst size of sound data from my soundsamplearray according to another data comes from CANBUS and send it via i2s.
`HAL_I2S_Transmit_DMA(&hi2s3, SoundPack, SIZE);`
After sending soundpack it takes volume parameters from CANbus and arranges amplifiers volume via I2C.

```
    if(SimRxData.SpeakerModeSelect== FRONT_REAR)
    {
        SetVolumeFR(TempVolume); //WARNING: CHECK MAX VAL. 
    }
    else if(SimRxData.SpeakerModeSelect== RIGHT_LEFT)
    {
        SetVolumeRL(TempVolume);
    }
```

At this moment. After dma transmit function runs my i2c connection getting start to break and. I get bus busy error. If I comment dma transmit function, there is no problem at I2C.
I'm using I2C3 and I2S3.
This pictures belongs to SDA line, before and after i2S transmit dma fuction. At after, there are little bit noise over sda but seems not so much. This noise may cause adress mismatching ?[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: With that description and detail, it could be anything. Are you sure the I2C operations are not made simultaneously, for example in a DMA callbacks?

Comment: @Justme Nope there is only one polling method for i2C, and  there is DMA for i2S.

Comment: It could be worth reading mcu Errata sheet. I remember on F103, the I2C has internal chip (hardware) conflict with other component and it stops working if they are both enabled simultaneously.

Comment: @akwky I just read and there is a statement like this "In the I²C standard, it is allowed to send a Stop only at the end of the full byte (8 bits +
acknowledge)" so I'm thinking if my SDA line has noise as u see, this noise may cause a mismatch adressing phase and cause of this stop generate bit function does't work. They says also "A software workaround consists in asserting the software reset using the SWRST bit in the I2C_CR1 control register." I will try this.

Comment: Problem solved. This was application-spesific problem. Problem is related to pull-up resistor which connected to SCL. I used both of external and internal pull ups. Externals was 4K7 ohms. But there was missconnection at SCL pin and external didn't connected and internal pull-up on SCL does not enough to pull SCK line to VDD. This makes down SDA after for a while. Btw, I still don't know why I was not getting any fault on I2C if I disabled I2S dma tansmit function. Thx.